# select result in order of maximum match in a string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string column Countries in table tblCountry for example 'India, Austrailia, US, UK'. 
Now whatever sequence is supplied example 'US, Germany, UK, India, Russia' I have to split the 
string on space basis and then display results of all where even a single country is present in the Column Countries  value.
Upto this I had achieved by below query. Now the difficult part is I have to display the result first which 
has maximum match of column value.

For example if below are the column values:

```
'India, Austrailia, US, Italy'
'India, Malaysia, Austrailia, US, UK'
'UK, Austrailia, France, Korea, India'
'China, India, US, UK'
```

and the input string is 'Austrailia, UK, India, Korea, Germany' then the result should be in maximum match comes at top like below:
  Output is most matched countries on top by relevance like below for above case

```
 'UK, Austrailia, France, Korea, India'   
 'India, Malaysia, Austrailia, US, UK'   
 'India, Austrailia, US, Italy'  
 'China, India, US, Brazil'


declare @matchCount int = 0;

SET @matchCount = (SELECT count(Item)  
        FROM dbo.SplitCountry('Austrailia, UK, India, Korea, Germany' , ',') 
        where Countries like '%'+Item+'%')

SELECT Countries, CASE 
WHEN @matchCount >0 THEN @matchCount 
     ELSE 0
  FROM tblCountry
```

I used a function to split the string 'SplitCountry'. Also I cannot use full text here

Comment: what is maximum match? It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you provide desired output as well?

Comment: Desired output is here  'UK, Austrailia, France, Korea, India'   
                  'India, Malaysia, Austrailia, US, UK'   
                  'India, Austrailia, US, Italy'  
                 'China, India, US, Brazil'

Comment: I also mentioned and edit the output in my above post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a lot of research and I got a easy solution for my problem. Below query is perfectly working for me

DECLARE @patterns TABLE  (
pattern VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @patterns VALUES ('%india%'), ('%france%'), ('%US%'),('%UK%')

;WITH CTEORD AS 
(
SELECT a.*,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By country Order By p.pattern) AS RN FROM Countries a 
JOIN @patterns p
 ON (a.country LIKE p.pattern)
)

select MAX(RN) As RN,country,
 from CTEORD group by country
 order by RN desc

Answer (score 0):

You have to

- create temp table #t1 (CountriesID, Country)
- create temp table #t2 (Country)
- populate #t1 by using you split function, so you have:

  CountriesID Country

  1 India

  1 Austrailia

  1 US

  1 Italy

  2 India

  2 Malaysia

  2 Austrailia

  2 US

  2 UK

  3 ... and so on
- populate #t2 by using you split function so t# contains the input values
- finally:

SELECT #t1.CountriesID, c.Countries

FROM #t1

INNER JOIN #t2 on #t2.Country = #t1.Country

INNER JOIN tblCountry c ON c.CountriesID = #t1.CountriesID

GROUP BY #t1.ID,  c.Countries

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Comment: This is a very good idea. But there are around more than 50 countries\Cities in every row countries. And the number of rows are more than 1000 and increasing rapidly. It means #t1 will contain 50*1000 rows. Is it good performance wise? I was more looking for thing work with LIKE or CHARINDEX keywords. If not then this may be the only option.

Comment: temp table can handle millions rows, so if you create the index on #t1 after populating #t1, performance should be OK. The slowest part will be populating temp tables by executing Split function for every row in #t1, but that has to be done anyway for any chosen method.

Comment: Do I need to run a loop over the whole original table to create create #t1 table? Is there any other way than looping.

Comment: looping should not be a problem - you need to do just 1000 iterations. But if you don't like it, you can create a huge SQL script with one select query and run it as dynamic sql "insert into #t1 (CountriesID, Country) exec (@sql)", but that may be not safe (sql injection). If you choose the fastest Split function, then your query will be quick.

Comment: Thanks Anton but 1000 is what I have right now, and soon it will store an average of 50000 records. That means 50 * 50000 in the temp #t1. Also I am concerned that where the temp table will be stored because I have a database limit of 200MB only. Are these temp table will be stored like normal table until they are dropped or there size will not impact anything? Please advice

Comment: temp tables are stored in tempdb database which is recreated after every sql server restart. # temp tables are automatically dropped when SP finishes its execution or connection/session is closed. Try it with 10M rows by duplicating the data, it may take a few minutes to populate it (depending on your hardware), but final select should be quick (seconds). Try ti execute it first with some dummy constant value and then compare it with usage of Split function. If it will be slow because of slow Split function, you may need to rewrite TSQL Split to CLR (CLR is better than TSQL with string split)

Comment: I have a option to limit the keywords in input string(5 word). But in the Country column the words can be of any numbers  so splitting them and create a temporary table of 50000 * 100 rows is not a wise step for me. As I found that temp table occupy the same storage as physical table until they are not dropped and I have db storage limit. What I do is send 5 keywords from C# and match one by one in every row through LIKE operator but how can I get the maximum match on Top. One option is get all 20 permutation of 5 Keywords and then inner join all. Can you please also advice on this approach.